# Google app engine jobs in datastore admin freeze

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to delete one kind of entity at once from GAE datastore admin page. The problem is, I fired two jobs for deleting one kind (same kind). After one job successfully finished, another just freeze, preventing other jobs from being run.

The job description is:

```
Job #158264924762856ED17CF
Overview
Running
Elapsed time: 00:00:00
Start time: Tue Nov 20 2012 09:58:27 GMT+0800
entity_kind: "CacheObj"
Counters
```

How can I clear these jobs? Deleting them from task queue won't help much, they are still inside datastore admin page.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, please fill an issue on: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but the frozen job didn't prevent new jobs to be executed. However, getting a frozen job is misleading. My workaround:

- Go to the Datastore Viewer
- Select _AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation as kind
- Find the frozen job
- Delete it
- You might get an error saying that the app failed
- Go back to the Datastore Admin, and check that the job is no longer there